# Is there a way to have python dict literals evaluated as ordered dicts?

Tags: python, parsing, eval, python-2.6

Disclaimer: Yes I realize what I'm suggesting is crazy, I have a very special (ab)use case.

Within a particular exec I want dictionary literals to evaluate to ordered dictionaries, so I can preserve the original ordering from the exec'd code.

I tried replacing __builtin__.dict before the exec (being very careful to restore it after), however that doesn't affect dict literals, only the dict call itself.

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> __builtin__.dict = list
>>> exec "a={}"
>>> a
{}
>>> exec "a=dict()"
>>> a
[]
```

Obviously there is the dis module, but that's the nuke the site from orbit approach.

Is there some other way I can hook into the evaluation of dict literals and change what happens?

P.S. for Python2.6

Comment: I think you'd have to replace the dict literals with `dict( tuples here )` in the source, as dict literals are syntax, so it's not Python if they're not interpreted as dicts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to have a look at the [ast](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) module, with which you could `ast.parse` the given code and replace every `ast.Dict` entry with the corresponding constructor call.

(But, sorry, it seems that you want something really strange.)

Comment: I forgot about ast, that's probably better than dis, although definitely in the same category.

Comment: Well, let's reason: you need to change a program's behavior (no matter if it's Python or whatnot). You either change it on source level, or after compilation or you patch the execution environment. `{}` cannot be affected by the environment (unless you patch the interpreter). So you either patch the bytecode, or, more robust, portable and debugging-friendly, the source.